# Get all textboxes of an form with their name in ascending order

Tags: c#, sorting, visual-studio-2013

I have total of 36 textboxes in a form with name of textboxes as txtBox1 , txtBox2..... to txtBox36. Among them some of the textBox are filled on form_load event.

I want to get all the text boxe names which are empty in ascending order.

What i have tried :

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 36; j++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(control.Name.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What it is giving is in random order

```
txtBox26
txtBox28
txtBox31
txtBox34
txtBox33
txtBox30
txtBox27
txtBox29
txtBox25
txtBox14
txtBox16
txtBox19
txtBox21
txtBox18
txtBox17
txtBox23
txtBox24
txtBox13
txtBox7
txtBox10
txtBox6
txtBox3
txtBox11
txtBox12
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` to get all sorted by name text boxes:

```
var allTexboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
var sortedTextBoxes = allTexboxes
                     .Where(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Text))
                     .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
                     .ToArray();
```

Then you can get name by this way:

```
var name = sortedTextBoxes[0].Name;
```

If you want just names as string array:

```
var allTexboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
var sortedNames = allTexboxes
                 .Where(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Text))
                 .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
                 .Select(i => i.Name)
                 .ToArray();
```

and to get name:

```
var name = sortedNames[0];
```

Comment: && String.IsNullOrEmpty((TextBox)i.Text)

Comment: Do you need anything besides `using Linq;` for this? I tried it out of interest and got an error saying `ControlCollection does not contain a definition for Where`.

Comment: yes it is giving error, @Equalsk i just want to the retrieve the textBox Name in ascending order. Sorry i am noob here.

Comment: @Roma how can i get the textBox name now

Comment: @Sdp, you can cast collection to array  and then use index (`sortedTextBoxes[0].Name`). Is it what you want?

Comment: @Sdp, see edited answer, I added `.ToArray()`  at the and of `LINQ` query

Comment: its giving me 
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:  
@Roma

Comment: @Roma still same poblem txtBox name retrieved is in random order :-(

Comment: @Sdp, did you make some changes in code from answer? I have tested this solution and it works.

Comment: Can confirm the solution works just fine for me too.

Comment: sorry it is working now :) You are a saviour, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function for geting controls recursivly, which can be usefull in case of containers :

```
public static List<T> GetControls<T>(this Control _mainControl, int _maxDepth = 10) where T : Control
    {
        if (_maxDepth < 0)
            return new List<T>();

        List<T> ObjectList = new List<T>();

        foreach (Control CurrentControl in _mainControl.Controls)
        {
            if (CurrentControl is T)
            {
                ObjectList.Add(CurrentControl as T);
            }
            else
            {
                ObjectList.AddRange(CurrentControl.GetControls<T>((_maxDepth - 1)));
            }
        }
        return ObjectList;
    }
```

Then you can do :

```
var OrderedTextboxes = this.GetControls<TextBox>().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```